# js jquery forward saved event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

I´m holding back some of my native click events on hyperlinks, to check if the result page holds a content.

Im saving the jquery event object and after some checkings, i want to let the event go its natural way.

- Capture Event
- Check for Contents
- If contents available

  - forward event as it was fired
- else

  - do nothin

At this moment, I just saving the `"href"` property and want to set it to the `document.location.href` if true comes back.

**Now, the question:** Is there a better way to forward/reraise the existing event, than setting the href to the `document.location.href`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `document.location.href` would be fine, and also seems like the simplest option to me.

But just for the sake of exploring other options, you could also have js click the link for you if it's deemed as safe.  For example, something like this.

```
$('a').click(function() {
  if( !$(this).is('.content-verified') ) {
    var self = this;
    // Do your content checking here, with the callback for verified good
    // content being $(self).has_good_content();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});

// Callback for good content
// should be something like this:
$.fn.has_good_content = function() {
  return $(this).each(function() {
    $(self).addClass('content-verified');
    $(self).click();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for the jQuery Deferred object. New in jQuery 1.5+

```
function done() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred(),
        timeout;

    timeout = setInterval(function() {
        if (contents available) {
            clearInterval(timeout);
            return dfd.resolve();
        }
    }, 50);

    return dfd.promise();
}

$('#my-link').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $.when(done())
        .then(function(o) {
            //unbind the click event that prevents the default action and click on the link afterward
            $this.unbind('click').click();
        });
});
```

So what is happening is it will wait for the resolve/success state from the `done` function. You are telling your click event to wait because `done` is using the Deferred object and has promised to return something.

I have put a `setInterval` to check every 50 mili seconds if the contents have loaded then I `resolve` the Deferred object therefore the `then` in click event will be called.

You can pass an object to `dfd.resolve();` like this `dfd.resolve({ test: true });`. Then the `o` argument in `then` will have `o.test` .

I have used Deferred several times and I really liked it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thats good to know, thanks. But @groovetrain got a little easier method. I dont know why, but i just forgot, that if the content is verified, i can unbind the click handler, since i´m going away from the page. So i prefer your and groovetrain solution, where i on content-check-finished will just unbind and click again.

Comment: I was under the impression that the contents will be available at some point in the future but you dont know exactly when so I did this. But ya if it takes one check to see if they are available this method is unnecessary but Deferred is quite powerful for the right purpose. Good luck!